# How can I make my do while loop work the way I want it to?

Tags: java, do-while

I am trying to make my code loop the prompt to enter rectangle length and width if the user answers yes to the *"Continue?:(y/n)"* prompt.

It is currently looping the *"Continue?:(y/n)"* part not the *"Enter Length: "* and *"Enter Width: "* part. 
Any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Day1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Grand Circus' Room Detail Generator!");

        double length = 0.0;
        double width = 0.0;
        double area = 0.0;
        double perimeter = 0.0;

        System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
        length = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter Width: ");
        width = scanner.nextInt();

        area = length * width;
        perimeter = 2 * (length + width);

        System.out.println("Area: " + area);
        System.out.println("Perimeter: " + perimeter);

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response;

        do {
            System.out.print("Continue? (y/n):");
            response = sc.next();
        } while (response.equals("y") || response.equals("Y"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String response;
do {
```

before

```
System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
```

Why would anything outside of your loop body (the stuff between `do {` and `} while (...)`) be repeated?

Comment: Thank you... that's all I needed.